# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, mysqli, hosting

I'm quite new to php and I tested this code on my local server and it was working fine but when I uploaded it to webserver I started getting the following errors.

This is the Code :

```
    "if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT members.id, permissions.name FROM members,permissions WHERE username=? AND password=? AND members.type=permissions.id" )){
    $username=$input["user"];
    $password=$input["pass"];
    $configsalt=$config["salt"];
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,md5($password.$configsalt));
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$type);
    $stmt->fetch();"
```

The line 39 is "$stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,md5($password.$configsalt));"

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in 
/home/hotel132/public_html/bulbmg/index.php on line 39

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_admin() (previously declared in /home/hotel132/public_html/bulbmg/includes/config.php:22) in /home/hotel132/public_html/bulbmg/includes/config.php on line 28

I don't know why the second error is occuring!!!
    '

```
.......
//Functions

function is_admin(){
if($_SESSION['type']=="admin"){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}  //line 28
?>'
```

Kidly help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use literals, try using variables.

The error: 
Are you including or requiring file(s) more than one time? Try [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)/[require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Otherwise check [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

**EDIT:**
*Have you tried this?*

```
if (!function_exists('is_admin')) {
    function is_admin(){
    if($_SESSION['type']=="admin")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bmla, I am not sure why it doesn't work when I am trying to host it....It's working fine in my development server but not on the cloud.I'm pretty new to PHP..Can you kindly explain me what this could be??As far I think this could be due to diffrent versions of PHP or different hosting platform.

Comment: I don't know why it only works in you development environment. Have you tried the code I added in the edit or using include_once/require_once wherever appropriate? Also, are you using any dependencies or libraries that may interfere with your code or each other?